# ASP.Net Core Application Parts view not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm testing ASP.Net Core Application Parts example:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/mvc/advanced/app-parts/3.0sample1

When running the example project, calling the IndexView action on MySharedController, the view "Index" is not found, even if in the stack trace I see that the search path is correct.

"InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Views/MyShared/Index.cshtml /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml"

Comment: Run the application and watch what it is actually doing using Fiddler or Google DevTools

Comment: Nothing special from Fiddler or GDev Tools, just a 500 error. Called controller and action is correct (debug is stopping in the method).Seems a search path problem, even if the error message in the stack trace shows correct path